# Mysql query performance issue with left join

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables in database. First table has 150k records, 2nd table has 175k records and 3rd table has 2.1 million records. I need the output using above 3 tables. So I joined above 3 table using inner join and I got the output with 1.5k records, but it takes 8 hours of time to execute.

I used primary keys in joining tables. How to increase the performance?

I have tried to add indexes and below is the script & code

Below table has 150k records

```
 CREATE TABLE `us_input_opp_oppheader` (
    `accountId` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `accountName` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
    `objectId` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `processType` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
    `description` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
    `noOfLines` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`accountId`,`objectId`),
    KEY `objectId` 
    (`objectId`,`description`,`accountId`,`accountName`,`noOfLines`)
    )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Below table has 175k Records

```
CREATE TABLE `us_input_opp_oppitem` (
  `objectId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `createdBy` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `changedBy` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `numberInt` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`objectId`,`numberInt`),
  KEY `objectId` (`objectId`,`createdBy`,`changedBy`,`numberInt`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Below table has 2.1 million records

```
CREATE TABLE `us_input_opp_oppsalesteam` (
  `transactionNumber` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `item` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `partnerFunction` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `partnerFunctionText` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transactionNumber`,`item`),
  KEY `item` (`item`,`partnerFunction`,`partnerFunctionText`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


SELECT oh.objectId, oh.description, oi.`createdBy`, oi.`changedBy`, oh.description, oh.processType, 
os.`item`, os.`partnerFunction`, os.`partnerFunctionText`     
FROM us_input_opp_oppheader oh 
LEFT join us_input_opp_oppitem oi ON oi.objectId = oh.objectId 
LEFT join us_input_opp_oppsalesteam os ON os.transactionNumber = oh.objectId 
WHERE (os.Item != 0 OR oh.noOfLines = 0) 
GROUP BY oh.objectId, oi.numberInt;
```

Comment: If you put EXPLAIN before your SELECT in the query you can see if your indexes will be used.

Comment: You say NOTHING about indexes

Comment: You have two different data types for your objectid/transactionnumber, `bigint(20)` and `varchar(100)`. It requires casting and prevents the efficient use of indexes, so use the same type for these (preferable bigint). Also having an index `us_input_opp_oppitem (objectId, numberInt)` should be beneficial here. Even more benefical would be to add the explain output to your question (see Remcos comment). Also be aware that your query will show unspecific values for e.g. `os.item`, as it's not in the `group by`. Actually, `os` is not even a valid alias, so make sure you use the correct query.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be take a shorter time if you use inner join or join instead of left join